# Do I need a virtual destructor for boost::ublas matrix?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, virtual-destructor

Do I need virtual destructor when I am using boost::ublas matrix ?

By the way, my class is a template class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you have this?

```
template <typename Whatever>
struct my_class
{
    // ...

    boost::ublas::matrix m;
};
```

There's nothing here that dictates you have a virtual destructor.

---

You want a virtual destructor when you intend on having users publically derive from your class. So that question should be "Users will publically derive from my class, do I need a virtual destructor?". Yes, you do.

The reason is that doing this leads to undefined behavior:

```
struct base {}; // no virtual destructor
struct derived : base {};

base* b = new derived;

// undefined behavior, dynamic type does not match static type,
// and the base class does not have a virtual destructor
delete b;
```

This does not:

```
struct base { virtual ~base(){} }; // virtual destructor
struct derived : base {};

base* b = new derived;

// well-defined behavior, dynamic type does not match static type,
// but the base class has a virtual destructor
delete b;
```

Note that it has *nothing* to do with what members there are in the base class. You *always* need a virtual destructor if users will be deleting derived classes through a pointer to a base class.

---

<sub>I would recommend you [get a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) so you know what it does, because it sounds like you just throw things around and hope it works, which isn't a very good approach.</sub>

Comment: yes @ first question tht's what my class look like , and yes I intent to have users derive from my class . really thanks alot :)

Comment: @ismail: Oh, then to clarify: you do need `virtual`.